# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "</>"

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

*Adding this question because I didn't easily find the answer online.*

I am trying to use `react-testing-library` to test that a component renders correctly. However I get numerous errors that don't seem to help much.

Here is my test file (`report.test.ts`, alongside the component in the code):

```
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";
import Report from "./Report";

test("component", () => {
  const reportData = {
    name: "test-report-name",
    url: "test-url"
  };
  const { getByText } = render(<Report report={reportData} />);

  expect(getByText("test-report-name")).toHaveAttribute("href", "test-url");
});
```

When I try to run the test, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "</>"`. There is a red squiggly line in VS Code that on hover says `Argument of type 'Report' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any>'`.

Even if I change the Report tag to be simply `<div />`, then I get `Cannot find name 'div'`.

What is the problem with my test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test file extension should be recognised as a file that uses the React syntax (eg. `tsx`), and React should be defined using `import React from "react";`.

When using the JSX syntax, it seems React must be defined in the file, and also the file type must be recognised as one that uses React. So presumably a similar change would be required if the test file had the `js` extension.

Comment: Yeah, in my case I had to change "ts" to "tsx" in my test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: whenever you type `<div>Foo</div>`, `<Component />` or other JSX syntax that's not standard JavaScript. If you open the browser console and type `<div />` you'll get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

So how does the browser manage to read your XML code? Depending on your configuration you have something that converts JSX to plain old JavaScript—usually it's [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx).

Whenever you type `<div className="foo">Hello</div>` that code is translated to `React.createElement('div', {className: 'foo'}, 'Hello')`. As a matter of fact you could code using `createElement` and skip the whole JSX thing if you wanted to.

This is true for your tests too.

In your example `render(<Report report={reportData} />)` will be translated to `render(React.createElement(Report, {report: reportData}, null))` before your test runs.

And that's why you have an error; you're trying to access the method `createElement` of `React` but you didn't import it.

Importing React will fix your test.