# How do i simulate a button click in Enzyme React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Simulating a button click seems like a very easy/standard operation. However,  I can't get it to work in reacyt Jest.js tests.

Below is what i have tried, what the error message is and my code that i want to test

The code i would like to test

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { 
      showAssessment: false
    };
  }
  assessment = (boolean) => {
    this.setState({
      showAssessment: boolean
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.showAssessment === true) {
      return <App
          assessment = {
            this.assessment
          }
      />
    } else {
      return ( < div className='container-fluid' style={landingPage}>
        <
            Component1 / >
        <
          button className='btn btn-dark' style={matchToolButton} onClick = {
          () => this.assessment(true)
        } >  Match Tool < /button> < /
            div > )
          }
          }

          }
```

The Test that i have written:

```
import React from 'react';

import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import Home from './Home';


test ('Home Button', () => {
    it ('It calls assessment function when clicked', () => {


        const wrapper = mount(<Home/>); // rednoing the home componenet/ testing
         wrapper.instance().assessment = jest.fn(); //if this isn't working try wrapper.instance().assessment

        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.assessment).toHaveBeenCalled();// see comment on line 14 keep the same

    });

    });
```

The error message that i am getting

```
FAIL  src/Home.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Bucket/dsp_poc2_uwe/front-end/src/Home.test.js: Unexpected token (12:30)
        10 | 
        11 | 
      > 12 |         const wrapper = mount(<Home/>); // rednoing the home componenet/ testing
           |                               ^
        13 |          wrapper.instance().assessment = jest.fn(); //if this isn't working try wrapper.instance().assessment
        14 | 
        15 |         wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with the `simulate` function.
Do you have `enzyme-adapter-react-16` added as project dependency and configured?

Comment: yes I have got added in my project dependency but i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **renderprops.cjs.js** instead of **renderprops.js?**. This solved my issue.

That libraries depends on the es-modules version of @babel/runtime, which needs to be used with webpack or rollup.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have test(... it(... in your test. That can't run. It should be describe(... it(...

Secondly React Testing Library makes it pretty easy what you're trying to achieve (replaces enzyme):

[react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)

```
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

describe('Home Button', () => {
  it ('It calls assessment function when clicked', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Home/>);
    fireEvent.click(getByText("Match Tool"));
    // test now whatever should be differnt after the button is clicked
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am getting the same Error:

Comment: ``` FAIL  src/Home3.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/Bucket/dsp_poc2_uwe/front-end/src/Home3.test.js: Unexpected token (12:38)
        10 |     it('It calls assessment fucntion when clicked',  () =>  {
        11 | 
      > 12 |         const { getByText } = render (<Home/>);
           |                                       ^
        13 | 
        14 |         fireEvent.click(getByText("Match Tool"));
````

Comment: here is a comment which could explain your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305638/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-expected